# Trying to show that a certain cubic in integer $n$ is not always solvable in integers $1 \le a,b,c < 2n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations, cubics

I have a [hypothetical] cubic equation in positive integers $n,a,b,c$, which is perhaps most compactly presented as
$$
2(2n-a)(2n-b)(2n-c) = 4n^2 - 2\bigl((a-b)^2+a+1\bigr)n + \bigl((a-b)^2c + b\bigr).
$$

By hypothesis, each factor on the left-hand side is positive. I’m trying to prove that there are an infinite number of positive integers $n$ for which corresponding integers $a,b,c$ cannot be found to satisfy the equation.

Any hints or references on similar problems would be appreciated.